# Spark on Dataproc: possible to run more executors per CPU?

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-dataproc

I am running Spark 1.6.2 on Google Cloud Dataproc (so Dataproc version 1.0). My cluster consists of a few of `n1-standard-8` workers, and I am running one executor per core (`spark.executor.cores=1`).

I see that my overall CPU utilization never gets above 50%, even though each worker is running the right number of executors (I'm leaving one core on each worker for OS, etc.).

I'm wondering if it's possible at all to somehow run more executors on each worker to utilize the cluster more fully? If so, what are the settings that I need to specify?

The `lscpu` dump on the worker machines looks like this:

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                8
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-7
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    4
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 62
Model name:            Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU @ 2.50GHz
Stepping:              4
CPU MHz:               2500.000
BogoMIPS:              5000.00
Hypervisor vendor:     KVM
Virtualization type:   full
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              30720K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-7
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default, YARN only schedules containers (spark executors in this case) based on memory, not on the number of cores they're requesting. Dataproc sets executor memory so that there are 2 executors per node.

`spark.executor.cores` essentially ignored in the context of YARN, but it *is* used to decide how many tasks to run in parallel. If you're lowering `spark.executor.cores`, but not executor memory, you are actually reducing parallelism!

You should instead leave executor memory alone and bump up `spark.executor.cores`. On an n1-standard-4, you should be able to raise `spark.executor.cores` from 2 to 4 with no problem.

If you try to set `spark.executor.cores` higher than the number of YARN vcores on a node, Spark will complain. You can fix this by setting `yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores=<large-number>`. Then, `<large-number>` will be the new upper bound.

Depending on how I/O bound your job is, you can easily double or quadruple `spark.executor.cores`, if not more. Writing files to GCS tends to be very I/O bound.

Note that while you can specify the spark properties when running a spark job, you'll only be able to specify that YARN property when creating a cluster:

- Job properties: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/dataproc/jobs/submit/spark
- Cluster properties: https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/cluster-properties

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed answer. I will give it a try shortly. To clarify what I'm trying: Say I have 2 workers with n1-standard-4 CPUs each. Right now I run max 5 Spark executors on this ( to leave 1 on each worker for OS and to leave 1 for Spark's App Master). So my question is can I run say 2 or 3 executors per each remaining CPU? (i.e. say 15 instead of 5). I will try your suggestion. I know exactly what you mean re Yarn memory -- I've figured out how to handle that...

Comment: In theory you can by just lowering executor memory to 1GB per executor, which turns out to be 12 executors on an n1-standard-4 (because n1-standard-4 has 15GB of memory and 12GB for YARN). But that's less efficient -- you really want to run lots of tasks in fewer executors. That way they'll share broadcast data, share a cache, etc. So I still suggest bumping up spark.executor.cores.